# Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed if checkbox value doesn't have any record or empty

Tags: codeigniter

When adding records into the database. Some fields are shows as per selection that time some checkbox fields are not displayed. Then pass values is empty.

```
$data = array(
        'pro_name'=>$this->input->post('pro_name'),
        'c_id'=>$this->input->post('c_id'),
        's_id'=>$this->input->post('s_id'),
        'pro_price'=>$this->input->post('pro_price'),
        'c_name'=>$c_name,
        's_name' => $s_name,
        'power_consumption'=>$this->input->post('power_consumption'),
        'model'=>$this->input->post('model'),
        'type'=>$this->input->post('type'),
        'cutout_size'=>$this->input->post('cutout_size'),
        'cct' => substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('cct')), 0),  
        'feet' => substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('feet')), 0),         
        'p_application' => substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('p_application')), 0),  
        'p_desc'=>$this->input->post('p_desc'),
        'pro_status'=> '5'
    );
    //print_r($data); die();
    $this->db->insert('product',$data);
```

if cct column is not present in my form as per selection of field then it set the value to 0 or remove

> Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add `cct` in `$data` array

First, check if `cct` not empty then use `implode()`

```
if($this->input->post('cct')){
   $data['cct'] = substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('cct')), 0);
}
```

And same for others that are using `implode()`